# Oracle JDBC Read/Write Custom Collection Type

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a Java object which extends SQLData - Delivery. I'm going to read and write a collection of Delivery objects to and from the DB. I'm happy about the WRITE part. I think I need to improve on the READ part. How can I directly map oracle TABLE TYPE to a list of Delivery objects?

The code below has been changed to keep this post short. Hence, there might be some mistakes, but all the stored procs and the code is fine. I just feel like the READ part is very cumbersome - getDeliveriesByDlvryDt(). How can I improve it?

```
// Java code
public class Delivery implements Serializable, SQLData {
    private String custNbr;
    private String dlvryDt;

    (...)

    private String typeName = "DELIVERY_OBJ";
    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return typeName;
    }
    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        this.typeName = typeName; 
        custNbr = stream.readString();
        dlvryDt = stream.readString();

    }
    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {

        try{
            stream.writeString(custNbr);
            stream.writeString(dlvryDt);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


-- PL/SQL code
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DELIVERY_OBJ AS OBJECT
(   CUST_NBR         NUMBER,
    DLVRY_DT         NUMBER,
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DELIVERY_TBL IS TABLE OF DELIVERY_OBJ;

PROCEDURE delivery_upsert_1(
  p_deliveryList      IN DELIVERY_TBL)
IS
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO DELIVERY D
  USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE(p_deliveryList)) DL
  ON (D.CUST_NBR = DL.CUST_NBR and D.DLVRY_DT = DL.DLVRY_DT)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
      (CUST_NBR, DLVRY_DT)
      VALUES (DL.CUST_NBR, DL.DLVRY_DT)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
      SET D.CUST_NBR = DL.CUST_NBR, D.DLVRY_DT = DL.DLVRY_DT;
END delivery_upsert_1;

PROCEDURE get_delivery_by_dlvry_dt_3(
  p_DLVRY_DT           IN DELIVERY.DLVRY_DT%TYPE,
  p_deliveryList     OUT DELIVERY_TBL)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT DELIVERY_OBJ(D.CUST_NBR, D.DLVRY_DT) BULK COLLECT into p_deliveryList
  FROM DELIVERY D
END get_delivery_by_dlvry_dt_3;


// Java code
public void upsertDeliveries(Delivery[] deliveries){

    String query = "{call"+SCHEMA+"."+PACKAGE+".delivery_upsert_1(?)}";
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Connection con = null;

    try{
        //get connection
        ArrayDescriptor arrayDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("WMT_DELIVERY_TBL", con);
        ARRAY arrayUpdate = new ARRAY(arrayDesc, con,(Object[])deliveries);

        cs = con.prepareCall(query);
        cs.setObject(1, arrayUpdate);
        cs.execute();
    }catch(Exception e){
        logError(extractStackTrace(e));
    }finally{
        try{
            cs.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            logError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}



public DBDelivery[] getDeliveriesByDlvryDt(String dlvryDt) {
    String query = "{call"+SCHEMA+"."+PACKAGE+".get_delivery_by_dlvry_dt_3(?,?)}";
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Connection con = null;

    final String typeName = "DELIVERY_OBJ";
  final String typeTableName = "DELIVERY_TBL";

    try{
        //got the connection    
        cs = con.prepareCall(query);
        cs.setString(1, userName);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, typeTableName);
        cs.execute();

        Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) cs.getObject(2)).getArray();
        for(Object tmp : data) {
           Struct row = (Struct) tmp;
           System.out.println(row);                                            
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        logError(extractStackTrace(e));
    }finally{
        try{
            cs.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            logError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

UPDATE 1 - my final version of getDeliveriesByDlvryDt:

```
public DBDelivery[] getDeliveriesByDlvryDt(String dlvryDt) {
    String query = "{call"+SCHEMA+"."+PACKAGE+".get_delivery_by_dlvry_dt_3(?,?)}";
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    Connection con = null;

    final String typeName = "DELIVERY_OBJ";
  final String typeTableName = "DELIVERY_TBL";

    try{
        //got the connection    
        Map typeMap = conn.getTypeMap();
        conn.setTypeMap(typeMap);
        typeMap.put(typeName, Class.forName(Delivery.class.getName())); 

        cs = con.prepareCall(query);
        cs.setString(1, userName);
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.ARRAY, typeTableName);
        cs.execute();

        List<Delivery> deliveries = new ArrayList<Delivery>();
        Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) cs.getObject(2)).getArray();
        for(Object tmp : data) {
            deliveries.add((Delivery)tmp);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        logError(extractStackTrace(e));
    }finally{
        try{
            cs.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            logError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much it. Only thing coming to my mind is to close the conn at finally block.

Comment: It is actually quite fine to me.  Does it perform right?  In what direction do you feel this can be improved?

Comment: @Jorge_B In getDeliveriesByDlvryDt() I'd have to loop over Struct objects, extract fields one by one, and then construct Delivery objects. Is there a way to directly get Delivery[] from CallableStatement? Or is there an easier way of mapping fields from Struct to Delivery?

Comment: By JDBC you are bound to get objects implementing JDBC interfaces such as Struct... the way you have implemented is actually quite straight to the problem.  You can make it look a little more nice by playing with your Delivery class constructor, but it would be essentially the same.

You maybe can close the gap by using automatic bean populators like the one in Apache Commons, or an ORM which would populate instance beans out of your query/proc call, but it is as close as you can get (at least as far as I know).

Comment: @Jorge_B I see. So what's the point of overriding readSQL() from SQLData? Is it for reading single rows?

Comment: Didn't know it!  From the documentation looks like that it would bring you where you want to go, but you would still have to implement a class implementing SQLData.  Have a look at this:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/jdbc130.htm

Comment: @Jorge_B Thanks a lot! Don't know why I didn't find that documentation earlier. I wasn't setting TypeMap on the connection object. Now I can directly cast to my object - see my updated code version.